# Calculation of Fourier series

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Let us define function $$V(t) = \begin{cases}3,& \text{for $0\leq t < 6$}\\ 4,& \text{for $6\leq t < 12$} \\ 3,& \text{for $12\leq t < 18$} \\ 0,& \text{otherwise}. \end{cases}$$

What is the Fourier Series for $V?$

Will the usual formulas i.e $$a_n = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int _{-\pi}^{\pi}V(t)\cos(nt)dt,\quad b_n = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int _{-\pi}^{\pi}V(t)\sin(nt)dt$$ work ?

Any hint will be appreciated.

Comment: You don't just say "the" Fourier series when you have a non-periodic function.  You need to say what sort of Fourier series you want.  There is no Fourier series equal to your function on the whole real line, since your function is not periodic.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they will work if you want to calculate the series on $(-\pi;\pi)$. If you want to calculate it on interval $(0;18)$ things are getting harder. First, you need to extend the function on $(-18;18)$. The simplest way is to define a new function called $U$:

$$U(t)=V(t)+V(t+18)$$

Where $V$ is your function, modified to fulfill Dirichlet's conditions<sup>[1]</sup>. And then use the formulas

$$a_0=\frac{1}{2l}\int_{-l}^l U(u)du$$
$$a_n=\frac1l\int_{-l}^lU(u)\cos\frac{\pi nu}{l} du,
\quad b_n=\frac1l\int_{-l}^lU(u)\sin\frac{\pi nu}{l} du$$

where $l=18$. Of course $b_n=0$ for all $n$ because $U(t)$ is even. You use then the summation

$$a_0+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(
a_n\cos\frac{\pi n x}{l}+b_n\sin\frac{\pi n x}{l}
\right)$$

For example calculating $a_2$ we get:

$$a_2=\frac{1}{18}\int_{-18}^{18}U(u)\cos\frac{2\pi u}{18} du$$
$$=\frac{1}{18}\left(
3I_{-18}^{-12}+
4I_{-12}^{-6}+
3I_{-6}^{0}
+
3I_{0}^{6}+
4I_{6}^{12}+
3I_{12}^{18}
\right)$$

where $I_a^b=\int_a^b\cos\frac{\pi u}{9} du$. Mathematica gives the answer $a_2=-\frac{\sqrt 3}{\pi}$. You can see [the plot of partial sums](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/uaoq9s7tm6). Also, I wrote the following Mathematica code to get $a_n$:

```
l = 18;
u[x_] := Piecewise[{
  {3, x > -18 && x < -12},
  {4, x > -12 && x < -6},
  {3, x > -6 && x < 0},
  {3, x > 0 && x < 6},
  {4, x > 6 && x < 12},
  {3, x > 12 && x < 18},
  {0, x < -18 || x > 18}
}];
a[n_] := 1/l * Integrate[u[x] Cos[\[Pi] n x / l], {x, -l, l}];
```

<sup>[1]</sup> *values of the function at points of discontinuity will be equal to an average of one sided limits at this point*

Comment: @kamilo9875: I think in the formulas $\frac{1}{l}$ should replace by $\frac{1}{2l}.$ Can you  please do calculation for $a_2$ ?

Comment: @Arup I've added $a_2$ calculation. Formulas are correct, I checked in my book; also, added explicit formula for $a_0$ (it is defined as an average value of the function on the interval)

Comment: @kamilo9875: Thanks a lot.